# DAX/Power BI - Number Formatting

Tags: powerbi

How do I remove the $ from a number that is formatted as a currency? I have a financial statement and the client doesn't want to see dollar signs unless it's for a total row. See example below. I want to remove the $ and keep the ( ) when the number is negative. Willing to use some kind of FORMAT function if necessary, but keep in mind, I'm using both measures and columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column and apply `FORMAT` function:

```
= FORMAT(TableName[ColumnName],"#,##0.0;(#,##0.0)")
```